# When joining 2 hashes in Perl I get an extra element "undef"

Tags: perl, hash

I have two hashes and when I join them I get an extra element, "undef". Why?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;

my %foo = (
    "disable-notify",
    "start=s",
    "end=s"
);

test();

sub test() {
    my %bar = (
    "notify-disabled",
    "durtion=s",
    "help",
    "my-stuff"
);

my %poop = (%foo, %bar);
print Dumper(%poop);
}
```

Running the code gives me:

```
$VAR1 = 'notify-disabled';
$VAR2 = 'durtion=s';
$VAR3 = 'help';
$VAR4 = 'my-stuff';
$VAR5 = 'disable-notify';
$VAR6 = 'start=s';
$VAR7 = 'end=s';
$VAR8 = undef;
```

Where did this undef come from?

Comment: You aren't making your hashes correctly.  You need to supply a list of pairs of items to put in the hash: %foo = ('help', 1, 'my-stuff', 2); Perl expected you to supply an even number of items, but in the %foo case you only supplied three, so it filled in the 4th for you.  Take a look at the perlvar manual page for a full explanation.

Comment: **Always** add `use strict;` and `use warnings;` until you know **exactly** why this is recommended practice. At which point, you will most likely continue to use both of those pragmas.

Comment: This makes sense. But what I want to do is append %bar to %foo. In short, %foo would be a set of global options and %bat would be local to a particular command. So I'd have %global_args = ( .... ) and in the sub %local_arg = ( .... )... Then combine local and global.. to check the longer hash against GetOptions. Make sense? notify-disbled should not be the key for duration=s's value. They are separate.

Comment: **Also:** I believe you meant to use `print Dumper( \%poop )`

Comment: @gdanko then why dont you use arrays?

Comment: Well, I guess I could but it would require a lot of coding since I have everything in the script referencing %args->{"duration"} for example. And it's easier than setting a ton of variables. Though I may have to. I am going to try that. It will just require a good chunk of work.

Answer (score 5):

Well, for one thing, your hash syntax is a little wonky.  If you did it with big-arrow notation, it'd be more obvious:

```
my %foo = (
    "disable-notify" => "start=s",
    "end=s"
);
```

and

```
my %bar = (
    "notify-disabled" => "durtion=s",
    "help" => "my-stuff"
);
```

so, you have an un-even number of key-value pairs, and so "end=s" is being assigned as the key for an undefined value.  In short, you're not doing it right.

Answer (score 1):

Hashes have paired keys and values; your %foo hash has no value for the "end=s" key, so it is assumed to be undef.  You'd see it in %foo if you dumped that.  If you enable warnings (which you should always do), you will get a warning "Odd number of elements in hash assignment" on the line setting %foo.

Answer (score 1):

The following assigns odd elements to a hash:

```
my %foo = (
    "disable-notify",
    "start=s",
    "end=s"
);
```

This is why using [`=>` (fat comma operator)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_comma) instead of `,` is preferred when assigning keys and values to a hash. It will be much easier to spot such errors.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do option parsing with Getopt::Long?  If so you're confusing the 
option *value* HASH with the option *format* LIST.

You're initializing your hashes wrong; hashes always consist of pairs of elements.

You need to do this:

```
my %options = (start=>$your_default_start_here,
               end=>$your_default_end_here,
               # any other defaults here
);

my $options_ok = GetOptions(\%options,
      "disable-notify",
      "start=s",
      "end=s");
```

The arguments to GetOpt are a hash *reference* (initial value inputs and parsed value outputs), followed by a list of option specifiers.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. See, while --start is global, its default can vary depending on the action you're committing. So I do this:

```
my %global_args = (
    "help" => undef,
    "start=s" => undef,
    "end=s" => undef,
    "hosts" => undef,
    .....
);

do_status();
sub do_status() {
    my %local_args = (
       "duration" => undef,
       "status=s" = > undef,
       ...
    );

    my %args = (%global_args, %local_args);
    if(!GetOptions(\%args, keys %status_args)) {
        die "blah blah\n";
    }
}
```

Now when I run the script and print Dumper (\%args) I get:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'cluster' => 'music.mud',
      'end' => 'now  + 10 min',
      'start' => 'now',
      'property' => 'music'
};
```

Which is what I should be seeing. Thanks guys for the insight.